# Spring Security - Repository SocialUser

Tags: java, spring, security, service, repository

My problem is to get log in my web application with facebook. Normal login/register works fine but when it comes by social provider i have a problem, below are my importants files along others:

SecurityConfig.java

```
package pl.java.learning.todolist.infrastructure.config;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;

  @Autowired
  private UserSocialService userSocialService;

  @Override
  protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
  }

  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
      throws Exception {
    auth
        .jdbcAuthentication()
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .withDefaultSchema();
  }

  @Bean
  public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
    return authProvider;
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
  }

  @Override
  protected MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return userDetailsService;
  }

  @Bean
  public SimpleSocialUserDetailsService simpleSocialUserDetailsService() {
    return new SimpleSocialUserDetailsService(userDetailsService, userSocialService);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
          .headers().frameOptions().disable()
        .and()
          .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/login*", "/success*").anonymous()
          .antMatchers("/auth/**", "/signup/**", "/css/*", "/webjars/**","/js/*","/image/*").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
          .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
          .successForwardUrl("/tasks")
        .and()
          .logout()
          .logoutUrl("/logout")
          .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout-success").permitAll()
        .and()
          .apply(new SpringSocialConfigurer());
  }
}
```

SocialConfig.java

```
package pl.java.learning.todolist.infrastructure.config;

@Configuration
@EnableSocial
public class SocialConfig implements SocialConfigurer {

  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;

  @Bean
  public ConnectController connectController(
      ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator,
      ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
    return new ConnectController(connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository);
  }

  @Override
  public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer connectionFactoryConfigurer,
      Environment env) {
    connectionFactoryConfigurer.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookConnectionFactory(
        env.getProperty("spring.social.facebook.app-id"),
        env.getProperty("spring.social.facebook.app-secret")
    ));
  }

  @Override
  public UserIdSource getUserIdSource() {
    return new AuthenticationNameUserIdSource();
  }

  @Override
  public UsersConnectionRepository getUsersConnectionRepository(
      ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator) {
    JdbcUsersConnectionRepository repository =
        new JdbcUsersConnectionRepository(
            dataSource,
            connectionFactoryLocator,
            Encryptors.noOpText());
    repository.setConnectionSignUp(
        new SecurityImplicitConnectionSignUp(userDetailsManager()));
    return repository;
  }

  @Bean
  public JdbcUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager() {
    JdbcUserDetailsManager manager = new JdbcUserDetailsManager();
    manager.setDataSource(dataSource);
    manager.setEnableAuthorities(true);
    return manager;
  }
}
```

CustomSocialUser.java

```
package pl.java.learning.todolist.domain.social;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import pl.java.learning.todolist.infrastructure.persistence.BaseEntity;

@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString
@Table(name = "users")
public class CustomSocialUser extends BaseEntity {
  private String username;
  private String password;
  private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;
}
```

SimpleSocialUserDetailsService.java

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SimpleSocialUserDetailsService implements SocialUserDetailsService {

  private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
  private final UserSocialService userSocialService;

  @Override
  public SocialUserDetails loadUserByUserId(String userId)
      throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
    CustomSocialUser customSocialUser = userSocialService.findByUsername(userId);
    return new SocialUser(
        customSocialUser.getUsername(),
        customSocialUser.getPassword(),
        customSocialUser.getAuthorities());
  }
}
```

MyUserDetailsService.java

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

  private final UserRepository userRepository;

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByLogin(username);
    if(user == null) {
      throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
    }
    return new MyUserPrincipal(user);
  }
}
```

SecurityImplicitConnectionSignUp.java

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityImplicitConnectionSignUp implements ConnectionSignUp {

  public final UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager;

  @Override
  public String execute(Connection<?> connection) {
    String providerUserId = connection.getKey().getProviderUserId();
    User newUser = new User(providerUserId,
        "",
        Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER")));
    userDetailsManager.createUser(newUser);
    return providerUserId;
  }
}
```

UserSocialRepository.java

```
public interface UserSocialRepository extends JpaRepository<CustomSocialUser, Long> {
  @Query("SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.username = ?1")
  CustomSocialUser findByUsername(String username);
}
```

MyUserPrincipal.java

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyUserPrincipal implements UserDetails {

  private final User user;

  @Override
  public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return user.getRoles();
  }

  public Long getUserId() {
    return user.getId();
  }

  @Override
  public String getPassword() {
    return user.getPassword();
  }

  @Override
  public String getUsername() {
    return user.getLogin();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isEnabled() {
    return user.getEnabled();
  }
}
```

I got error like this:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Collection, at table: users, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(authorities)]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
    at pl.java.learning.todolist.TodoListApplication.main(TodoListApplication.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Collection, at table: users, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(authorities)]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:402)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Collection, at table: users, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(authorities)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:456)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:461)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserSocialRepository extends JpaRepository<SocialUser, Long> {
  @Query("SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.username = ?1")
  SocialUser findByUsername(String username);
}
```

1) If you use Spring Data and your class is extended from `JpaRepository`, you don't have to add `@Repository` annotation on your class.

2) In your method

```
SocialUser findByUsername(String username);
```

you return `SocialUser`, which is a class from Spring Social module and this class is not managed by JPA (that's why you receive an error). You should use either entity or Spring Data projection as a returned type in the method of your repository.

Let's assume that you have `Users` entity which should be something like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users {
    private String username;
    // ...
}
```

You can rewrite your method in the following way:

```
Users findByUsername(String username);
```

Then you can convert entity / projection to `SocialUser` in your service:

```
public UserDetails findByUsername(String username) {
    Users user = userSocialRepository.findByUsername(username);
    return new SocialUser(user.getUsername(), ...);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i did this in the same way as you wrote, but now i have a problem with Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Collection, at table: users

Comment: Generally problem is to create implementation SocialUserDetailsService which i want to "map" to my custom UserDetailsService which return custom UserDetails and i am trying from 1 week implement this, step by step but i don't know if i have a good direction for this problem :)

Comment: I use the class UserDetailsManager which create in my database table users with 3 columns, so i wanted to create entity like above to managed this but i think i do something incorrect, because i got error like above

Comment: Please update your question with the actual code and let's see what's wrong

Comment: Ok @MykolaYashchenko i updated my answer, there is more code than before, thank you for interested in my problem.

Comment: Looks like the problem is in your query. Try to rewrite it:

SELECT u FROM CustomSocialUser u WHERE u.username = ?1

Comment: Ok i rewrite this line but i got this error: Column "CUSTOMSOCI0_.ID" not found; SQL statement because ID in the table USERS doesn't exists, the problem is that the UserDetailsManager control this table USERS where id, version doesn't exists like in my Entity CustomSocialUser

Comment: Maybe in someway i can create table for social user which will be communicate with SocialUserDetailsService?

Comment: If you want to have store normal users and social users in separate tables - yes, you have to create a table. Otherwise, you can use UserRepository in your SocialUserDetailsService